# Deletar do localstorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Sou iniciante na área de js, estou desenvolvendo um código que armazena os dados em uma tabela e salva no localStorage, preciso que quando eu clicar no botão de excluir que aparece nessa tabela ele delete o item da tabela e do localstorage, alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal("#addAluno-modal");
let logged = sessionStorage.getItem("logged");
const session = localStorage.getItem("session");
let data = {
    alunos: []
};   

document.getElementById("button-logout").addEventListener("click", logout);

//Adicionar aluno
document.getElementById("addAluno-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const name = document.getElementById("name-input").value;
    const cel = document.getElementById("cel-input").value;
    const value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value-input").value);
    const date = document.getElementById("date-input").value;

    data.alunos.unshift ({
        name: name, cel: cel, value: value, date: date
    }); 
    
    saveData(data);
    e.target.reset();
    myModal.hide();

    getAlunos();

    alert("Aluno adicionado!");

});

checkLogged();

function checkLogged() {
    if(session) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("logged", session)
        logged = session;
    }

    if(!logged) {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
        return;
    }

    const dataUser = localStorage.getItem(logged);
    if(dataUser) {
        data = JSON.parse(dataUser);
    }

    getAlunos();

}

function logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("logged");
    localStorage.removeItem("session");

    window.location.href = "index.html";
}

function saveData(data) {
    localStorage.setItem(data.login, JSON.stringify(data));
}

function getAlunos() {
    const alunos = data.alunos;
    let alunosHtml = ``;

    if(alunos.length){
        alunos.forEach((item) => {
            
            alunosHtml += `
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">${item.name}</th>
                    <td>${item.cel}</td>
                    <td>R$${item.value}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn bi bi-trash" id="button-deletAluno"></button></td>
                </tr>
            `

        })
    }

    document.getElementById("alunos-list").innerHTML = alunosHtml;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <style>
        body::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 12px;               /* width of the entire scrollbar */
        }

        body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: white;        /* color of the tracking area */
        }

        body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: gray;    /* color of the scroll thumb */
        border-radius: 20px;       /* roundness of the scroll thumb */
}
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Alunos</title>
</head>
<body id="home">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">
                            <img src="./assets/logo-academia.png" id="logo-academia-navbar" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"  data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <div class="d-flex menu">
                    <a href="home.html"><button class="btn" type="button"><i class="bi bi-house-fill fs-4"></i></button></a>
                    <a href="transactions.html"><button class="btn" type="button"><i class="bi bi-currency-exchange fs-4"></i></button></a>
                    <a href="alunos.html"><button class="btn" type="button"><i class="bi bi-person-lines-fill color-secondary fs-4"></i></button></a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-person-circle fs-4"></i></button></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu logout" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                            <li><button class="dropdown-item" id="button-logout">Sair</button></li>
                        </ul>
                        
                      </div>
                </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="container-lg">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col d-flex mt-4 justify-content-start align-items-center">
                    <i class="bi bi-person-lines-fill color-primary icon-detail"></i>
                    <span class="fs-2">Alunos</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex mt-4 justify-content-end">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img src="./assets/coins-small.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 shadow-lg info">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Celular</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Valor Mensalidade</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Data de Entrada</th>
                                      </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                        <tbody id="alunos-list">
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <button class="btn button-float" data-bs-toggle="modal" 
            data-bs-target="#addAluno-modal"><i class="bi bi-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal fade" id="addAluno-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Adicionar Aluno</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
    
                <form id="addAluno-form">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name-input" class="form-label">Nome</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name-input" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="cel-input" class="form-label">Celular</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cel-input">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="value-input" class="form-label">Valor Mensalidade</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="value-input" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="entrada-input" class="form-label">Data de Entrada</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date-input" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary button-cancel" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn button-default">Adicionar</button>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </main>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./js/alunos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pra excluir algo do `localStorage` há o método `localStorage.removeItem('nomeDoItem')` mas se eu entendi bem tu precisa atualizar o valor salvo removendo um dado específico dele.

seria algo assim:

- adicionar um evento ao botao de excluir

```
function getAlunos() {
    const alunos = data.alunos;
    let alunosHtml = ``;

    if(alunos.length){
        alunos.forEach((item,indiceAluno) => {
            
            alunosHtml += `
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">${item.name}</th>
                    <td>${item.cel}</td>
                    <td>R$${item.value}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn bi bi-trash" id="button-deletAluno" onclick="deletarAluno(${indiceAluno})"></button></td>
                </tr>
            `

        })
    }

    document.getElementById("alunos-list").innerHTML = alunosHtml;
}
```

** aqui passei a referência do aluno usando o índice dele no array mas tu pode usar outro critério.

- remover o aluno do array propriamente dito e salvar os dados atualizados no localStorage

```
function deletarAluno(indiceAluno) {
    data.alunos = data.alunos.filter(function(item,idx) {
        return idx !== indiceAluno
    })

    saveData(data)
    // getAlunos()
}
```

- mostrar a lista atualizada na tela

```
getAlunos()
```

** O ideal é que tu não chame uma função dentro da outra como ficou ali no exemplo. Vai funcionar mas essa função `deletarAluno` vai estar lidando com muitas responsabilidades (deletar o aluno do array, salvar os dados, trazer os dados e atualizar na tela)